# Eclipse Galileo - How do I get all dirty editors to save on invocation of ant build?

Tags: eclipse, ant, autosave

I have lost more time than I care to relate from testing worthless builds resulting from unsaved code changes. I have searched the web for the magic setting I need to change & none work. My workflow is this:

1. make code changes
2. invoke ant build by double-clicking on target in ant window
3. hate life because code changes were not saved, and hence not included in build

There must somewhere be some trigger that detects an ant target invocation & prompts (or not, configurably) to save all dirty editors. Please, if anyone knows, tell me what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this bug sound like what you're seeing?

[Launch External Tool does not save dirty editors regardless of preference setting](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282581)

Comment: That bug report seems to indicate that the functionality worked in 3.4 (Ganymede) and is now broken in 3.5 (Galileo).

Comment: This looks VERY much like what I'm seeing, and I have in fact corrected the title above - I'm using Galileo, not Ganymede.  Glad to see I'm not going nuts.  I'll keep tabs on that bug listing.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

Windows->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching:
"Save required dirty editors before launching"

is this set to Always?

Comment: thanks - this was what I tried, to no avail.  Thanks for posting, in case someone with another version stumbles across it.